# Vim gf on command

Tags: vim, neovim

I have currently mapped some keys to open a certain file with `:e`, and that's working, but if I am editing a file, and then press that key combination, there is no way to go to the previous file. I would like to be able to go back with `gb`, so I was wondering if there is a command or some way of making that when I press some keys, it's the same than presing `gf` with the cursor over the file. Something like `:gf ~/file.md`.

Comment: `:h alternate-file`

Answer (score 0):

Vim has a concept called the “alternate file”—whenever a window switches buffers to display, the previous one is remembered in the buffer named `#` (you may know that `%` stands for the current file, and if you look at a US qwerty layout, you can see why the choice was made). In fact, you can also access these via registers of the same name.

So, `:edit #` or `:buffer #` will take you to the previous file. However, this is so common that vim provides a default mapping for it: `<C-6>`. On my machine, I actually have to type `<C-^>`, which is a nuisance, so I’ve rebound as

```
nnoremap <leader>` <C-^>
```